# Eloquent - Latest entry per user

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the latest db entry for today for each user.

This is what I have, but it is returning the first entry, instead of the last.

```
$activity = UserJourney::where('datetime', '>', date('Y-m-d 00:00:00') )
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->get()
            ->keyBy('user_id')
        ;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:

This is the output:

```
[
{
"id": 1562,
"user_id": 10,
"datetime": "2015-02-05 11:03:41",
"url": "/",
"device": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0",
"created_at": "2015-02-05 11:03:41",
"updated_at": "2015-02-05 11:03:41",
"deleted_at": null
},
{
"id": 1555,
"user_id": 148,
"datetime": "2015-02-05 09:20:56",
"url": "/dashboard/sales",
"device": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.94 Safari/537.36",
"created_at": "2015-02-05 09:20:56",
"updated_at": "2015-02-05 09:20:56",
"deleted_at": null
},
{
"id": 1553,
"user_id": 149,
"datetime": "2015-02-05 09:19:10",
"url": "/",
"device": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.94 Safari/537.36",
"created_at": "2015-02-05 09:19:10",
"updated_at": "2015-02-05 09:19:10",
"deleted_at": null
}
]
```

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($activity)` ?

Comment: Hi Michael, I outputted the JSON because the var_dump was quite large.  Is there something specific you were looking for?  It basically groups the results and only shows the first.

Comment: In MySQL `order by` and `group by` won't play together nicely. If you use Eloquent, then do this http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/